# Why doesn't my two-part route path work where a one-part path does?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

This is working:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/auth" element={<Auth/>} />
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

This is not:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Routes>
    <Route path="/auth/login" element={<Auth/>} /> // <====== ?!
  </Routes>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Can't figure out what's going on. Before I was able to set up compound routes, now nothing works.

Update. The whole code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';

const appRoute = (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/auth/1" element={<Home/>} /><=doesn't work
            <Route path="/auth" element={<Home/>} />/<=works
            <Route path="/" element={<Home/>} />
        </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>  
);

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById('app'));
root.render(appRoute );
```

Packages:

```
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
    "react-router": "^6.3.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0"
```

Solution found!
Instead of this

```
<script src="static/dist/bundle.js"></script>
```

should be this one

```
<script src="/static/dist/bundle.js"></script>
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue? The only difference is the path value? I see no reason why `path="/auth/login"` wouldn't work as written exactly in the provided code example.

Comment: I don't see a reason either but as soon as I write /auth/login in the browser it tries to redirect to some non-existing page (because of 404 I think).

Comment: Is the app deployed out on a server somewhere? How are you running the app? How are you navigating to the routes? Is this the complete routing code?

Comment: Everything is local. I will try to create jsfiddle.

Comment: @DrewReese I updated my code with the whole piece of code.

Comment: The code above appears to work without issue here in this running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/why-doesnt-my-two-part-route-path-work-where-a-one-part-path-does-ldbete), either with link navigation or direct URL input in the address bar. How are you running this code locally?

Comment: @DrewReese Thanks a lot! Figured it out! It turned out I wrote the script in the index wrong (see the update).